# PHP 4 to 7.3: how to convert with construct?

Tags: php, wordpress, deprecated

I looked at a lot of posts but I can't update a deprecated PHP code. Could somebody explain to me how update it?

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'vntd_widget_flickr' );

function vntd_widget_flickr() {
    register_widget( 'Vntd_Widget_Flickr' );
}

class Vntd_Widget_Flickr extends WP_Widget {


    function Vntd_Widget_Flickr() {
        
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'pr_widget_flickr', 'description' => 'Display a selected number of Flickr images.' );
        $this->WP_Widget( 'vntd_widget_flickr', 'Veented Flickr', $widget_ops );
    }
    
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );

        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $userid = $instance['userid'];
        $display = $instance['display'];
        $number = $instance['number'];

        echo $before_widget;

        if ( $title )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
            echo $after_widget;
    }
```

I tried changing:

```
function vntd_widget_flickr() {
    register_widget( 'Vntd_Widget_Flickr' );
}
```

into:

```
function __construct() {
    register_widget( 'Vntd_Widget_Flickr' );
}
```

but I still get some errors.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: _"but i've always errors_" What errors?

Comment: Change the function name _inside_ the class to `function __construct()`:  ... `function Vntd_Widget_Flickr() {`.  But unless you post the errors you receive, it will be difficult for us to help.

Comment: Laura, please edit your question to include the error message(s) you're seeing so we can help.

Comment: Hi guys i solved with:



``function __construct() {

$widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'pr_widget_blogpost', 'description' => 'The most recent posts on your site with an image.' );

parent::__construct( 'pr_widget_blogpost', 'Veented Blog Posts', $widget_ops );
}``


Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

You need to code following the documentation here : ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php )

Vntd_Widget_Flickr() is not a Wordpress function. You are probably not seeing the whole call stack. It is likely a theme or plugin function. Check for more errors and file references.